# Snowflake procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Hi Can anybody help me create a snowflake procedure in SQL for the below scenario

Input:

```
select table_schema,table_name,table_type from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA';
```

output: I need to insert this data along with ddl for each table_name using snowflake procedure
example, my backup table will contain table_schema,table_name,table_type,ddl_stt

```
create or replace procedure proc_getddl
is
v_tableschema varchar(30);
v_tablename varchar(30);
v_tabletype varchar(30);
v_getddl varchar(110);

cursor getddl is 
select table_schema,table_name,table_type,get_ddl('table','INVOICING')
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA';
begin
open getddl;
LOOP
fetch getddl into v_tableschema,v_tablename,v_tabletype,v_getddl;
EXIT WHEN getddl%NOTFOUND;
INSERT INTO backup_table
values (v_tableschema,v_tablename,v_tabletype,v_getddl);

END LOOP;
close getddl;
end proc_getddl;
```

please help

I tried something like this (but in oracle)I cant use this as get_ddl is not working for table_name unless specified

Answer (score 1):

The `GET_DDL(object_type, object_name)` function requires constants for both arguments.

Sample data:

```
CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA;

CREATE TABLE t1(id INT);
CREATE TABLE T2(col VARCHAR);
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT 1 AS c;
```

The idea is to built such query using:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(REPLACE(REPLACE(
'SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type, 
        GET_DDL(''<table_type>'', ''<table_name>'') AS DDL
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE CONCAT_WS(''.'', table_schema, table_name) =''<table_name>''
', '<table_name>', CONCAT_WS('.', table_schema, table_name))
,'<table_type>', CASE WHEN table_type = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE' ELSE 'VIEW' END)
, ' UNION ALL ') AS query
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA';
```

It generates:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type, 
        GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MYSCHEMA.T1') AS DDL
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE CONCAT_WS('.', table_schema, table_name) ='MYSCHEMA.T1'
 UNION ALL SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type, 
        GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MYSCHEMA.T2') AS DDL
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE CONCAT_WS('.', table_schema, table_name) ='MYSCHEMA.T2'
 UNION ALL SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type, 
        GET_DDL('VIEW', 'MYSCHEMA.V') AS DDL
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE CONCAT_WS('.', table_schema, table_name) ='MYSCHEMA.V'
```

---

Executing generated query:

```
DECLARE
   query STRING;
   res RESULTSET;
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(REPLACE(REPLACE(
'SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type, 
GET_DDL(''<table_type>'', ''<table_name>'') AS DDL
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE CONCAT_WS(''.'', table_schema, table_name) =''<table_name>''
', '<table_name>', CONCAT_WS('.', table_schema, table_name))
,'<table_type>', CASE WHEN table_type = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE' ELSE 'VIEW' END)
, ' UNION ALL ') AS query
INTO :query
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA';
   
   res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END
```

Output:

[image]